# VBA Powerpoint formatting

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I've written a piece of code to copy data from excel and paste it in a powerpoint presentation.

I constantly get the following error:

> Selection.ShapeRange : Invalid Request. Nothing Appropriate is
>   currently selected

Which relates to the following part of the code (where I am pasting the Excel data to the powerpoint slide and determine its position).

```
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
 pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 0
 pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0
 pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 1000
```

The weird thing is that this code used to work a couple of weeks ago (in excel 2016), but since today (I got downgraded to Excel 2010) it suddenly stopped working..

The full code I am using is as follows:

```
 'Step 1:  Declare variables

       Dim pp As Object
       Dim PPPres As Object
       Dim PPSlide As Object
       Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
       Dim MyRange As String
       Dim MyRange2 As String
       Dim TemplatePath As String

 'Step 2:  Open PowerPoint, add a new presentation and make visible

       Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
       Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
       pp.Visible = True

 'Step 3:  Start the loop through each worksheet

       'Step 3-A: Skip Excel sheets 1 till 8
       For Each xlwksht In Worksheets
       If xlwksht.Index >= 9 Then

       'Step 3-B:  Count slides and add new blank slide as next available slide number
       SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
       Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, 12)
       PPSlide.Select

 'Step 4:    Copy the Content section from Excel

       MyRange = xlwksht.Range("A1").Value & ":" & xlwksht.Range("A2").Value
       xlwksht.Range(MyRange).Copy

 'Step 5:  Paste the Content and adjust its position

       'Step 5-A: Determine the Path of the Template and apply it to the Powerpoint presentation

       PPPres.ApplyTemplate (TemplatePath & "\Template.potx")

       'Step 5-B: Determine the PasteType
       pastetype = xlwksht.Range("C1").Value  'Where C1 = "Image" for all images and tables
       PasteWidth = xlwksht.Range("D1").Value 'Where D1 = "Title" then picture will fill whole screen

       'Step 5-C: Based on the Pastetype paste the content in the presentation
       If pastetype = "Image" Then
             If PasteWidth = "Title" Then

                   'Step 5-C-1  Format only for Title Page
                    PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
                     pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 0
                     pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0
                     pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 1000
             Else

                   'Step 5-C-2  Format for Images
                    PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
                     pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 95
                     pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 20
                     pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 300
             End If
       Else

             'Step 5-C-3  Format for Normal tables
              PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
              pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 95
              pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 20
       End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the answer but plugging the suggestion in here will make it a whole lot more legible than including it as a comment:

Instead of this:

```
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
   pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 0
   pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0
   pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 1000
```

Try this:

```
With PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
  .Top = 0
  .Left = 0
  .Width = 1000
End With
```

Comment: Great! This worked perfectly! The pasting of pictures (datatype 2) are now working again, do you maybe know how I can get the regular pasting working again? In 2016 I used, which now doesnt work anymore in Excel 2010..  

     PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select

Comment: Generally you want to avoid selecting anything unless there's no other way. In this case, you can try PPSlide.Shapes.Paste (possibly adding a few DoEvents) then Set oSh = PPSlide.Shapes(PPSlide.Shapes.Count)  (having first Dimmed oSh as Shape).